# Add Envers revision to an existing and Not Audited table

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-envers

I have a table, populated with an import file.
Now I need to declare the related entity `AUDIT` and We have try to create a procedure for insert the revinfo in the Audit Table, by this way:

Extract from the DB the max REV and max RevTS

```
 @Query(value="select max(rev) from revinfo",nativeQuery=true)
 int findMaxRev();

 @Query(value="select max(revtstmp) from revinfo",nativeQuery=true)
 Long findMaxrevtstmp();
```

At this data we add a +1 value, and try to set it in this query:

```
@Query(value="insert into revinfo (`rev`, `revtstmp`) values (:rev, :revtstmp)", nativeQuery=true)
        void addRevInfo(@Param("rev") int rev, @Param("revtstmp")Long revtstmp);

@Query(value="insert into entity_h (id, audit_revision, action_type, audit_revision_end, audit_revision_end_ts ) "
    + "values (:id, :rev, 0, null, '2017-08-31 10:45:37')", nativeQuery=true)
    void addEnvers(@Param("id")long id, @Param("rev")int rev);
```

But when we run the addRevInfo query, We obtain this error:

```
`ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery()`.
```

If we run this same query directly in MySQLWorkbench, the insert run without problem.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this to you insert query:

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Query("....")
```

With that the EntityManager flush your changes otherwise not, and it permit to use the `executeUpdate()` instead of `exectueQuery()` works for

> the SQL statement, which returns a single ResultSet object

The executeUpdate instead is

> for SQL statement, which may be an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement
>   or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as an SQL DDL
>   statement.